# how do i create 2 docker-compose file for 2 separate VM?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a server A that need to communicate with Server B. Server A and Server B are to be deployed in 2 different machine.

docker-compose.yml for serverA, to run the image and create the network.
docker-compose.yml for serverB to run the image and join the network.

I am having the issue where my nginx in server A prompted error which prevented me from testing the creation of network in different VMs.

nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "ServerB" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

```
    version: "3.9" 
    services:
        ServerA:
            image: servera
            ports: 
                - "3443:443"
            networks:
                - myNet
    networks:
        myNet:
            name: custom_network
            ipam:
                driver: default
                config:
                    - subnet: 172.18.0.0/24
```

```
version: "3.9" 
services:
    ServerB:
        image: serverb
        ports:
            - "4443:443"
        networks:
            - my-proxy-net
networks:
    my-proxy-net:
        external:
            name: custom_network
```

```
server{
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privatekey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /TestPath {
        proxy_pass https://ServerB/TestPath/;

    }
}
```

how can i make changes such that server A is able to connect to server B when its up.

Answer (score 0):

Docker "bridge" networks are local to the host where they're created.  If the two containers aren't on the same host (or in the same VM) then they can't share networks or communicate this way.  You might be able to [configure an overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) separately from Docker's Swarm container orchestrator, but it's an involved setup.

The easier way to do this is to make sure each container publishes `ports:` out to its host (VM), and then use the other host's (VM's) IP address as the destination for the connection.

```yaml
# docker-compose.a.yaml, on 10.0.10.10
version: 3.8
services:
  ServerA:
    image: servera
    ports:
      - "3443:443"
    environment:
      - SERVER_B_URL=https://10.0.10.20:4443/TestPath/
# use the Compose-provided default: network with default settings
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.b.yaml, on 10.0.10.20
version: 3.8
services:
  ServerB:
    image: serverb
    ports:
      - "4443:443"
```

You will have problems with getting valid names in the TLS certificates, and you might find it useful to run a per-host HTTPS reverse proxy if you have that requirement.

At medium scale, a service-discovery system like Consul can help you remember what service is placed on which node.  At larger scale, a dedicated container-cluster system like Kubernetes will help you deploy and replicate these containers without manually placing them.